# How was the 10's complement calculated for the signed numbers below?

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary, binary-operations

In the image below, why is the given sum equal to +10, 627 ? 
Why the 10's complement of +9286 is 990714 and not 000714 (10000-9286) ?
Why was there an overflow in part b) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 10,627 is a mistake.  They probably changed the operands and forgot to update the result.

Ten's complement arithmetic works just like two's complement arithmetic.  I'll assume you are at least a bit familiar with that.

If you want to represent absolute values that require 5 digits, you need 6 digits, regardless of the base.  Complementation of $x$ is equivalent to computing $10^6-x$.  (In general, $b^n-x$ if $b$ is the base and $n$ is the number of digits.)

The arithmetic is done modulo $10^n$ (that is, $b^n$).  Hence everything in excess of $10^n-1$ is thrown away.  There's "overflow" also in case (d), even though it's not mentioned in the solutions.

Comment: Alright, suppose X<Y : I'm confused why sometimes when we wanna subtract X from Y so X-Y and we do X+(-Y)   <lets say here we're taking x and y of base 10> now we calculate the 10's complement of Y then add it to X to find our operation X-Y BUT what happens is that the number is positive so we should redo the 10's complement of it to get the right answer of X-Y, like should i take that as a rule? rule: If X-Y is +ve yet X<Y then we recomplement the result to get the true result?

Comment: Let's clear up a couple of points.  Subtracting $X$ from $Y$ gives $Y-X$.  I guess you mean "subtract $Y$ from $X$."  Also, when you say, "what happens is that the number is positive," which number are you talking about, $X-Y$?

Comment: In general, in 10's complement and in 2's complement, we don't "complement again."  If $X-Y > 0$ and the difference is representable with the available number of digits, it means that $X > Y$.  If $X$ is negative and $Y$ is positive and $X-Y$ is a negative number too large to be represented with the available digits, we have overflow, but "complementing again" doesn't fix the problem because the correct result is simply out of the representable range.